# Fire component method from another component on ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logic

I have this components:

```
class DashTopNav extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render(){
    return(<button></button>);
  }
}
class FltBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  methodToFired(){
  }
}

class XDashBoard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render(){
    return(<div className="XDashBoard">
        <DashTopNav onClick={call methodToFired on FltBox}  />
        <FltBox />
    </div>);
  }
}
```

I want to call a Method on FltBox (methodToFired) with a button on DashTopNav, but I cant find the way to call a function on a child component from another child component.

Comment: it would be better to put `methodToFired` into `DashTopNav` since you don't use it in `FltBox`, right?

Comment: No, because I need to ejecute something in FltBox when a button on DashTopNav is clicked :/

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely *not* what you want to be doing.

It seems to me like you want to extract the `methodToFired` from the `FltBox` component into your `XDashBoard` component since it seems to be a generic type of method and pass that down as a prop to your `DashTopNav` component or use the Flux pattern to fire an action from your `DashTopNav` that your `FltBox` then responds to.

Your example code is too barebones in order to make a correct assumption but below is a working refactor that would most likely suit you better.

```
class DashTopNav extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return(<button {...this.props}>Button</button>);
  }
}

class XDashBoard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  methodToFired (e) {
    console.log('fired');
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="XDashBoard">
        <DashTopNav onClick={this.methodToFired} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With React, you shouldn't try to access another component method arbitrarily. Basically, React is not design that way. React components react to changes in their props and states, so you can control them by chaging their props and states.

In you example, you can pass a class method from the parent component to `DashTopNav.onClick` and change the `FltBox` props inside that function, forcing `FltBox` to re-render and update when the user click `DashTopNav`.
If the final result of `FltBox` can be derived directly from that props change, then the `render` function is enough, if you need to perform a side effect as a reaction to the props change, then you can use React lifecycle methods like `didComponentUpdate`.

For example:

```
class DashTopNav extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render(){
    return(<button></button>);
  }
}

class FltBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  didComponentUpdate() {
    // Handle navButtonClick update 
  }
}

class XDashBoard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       navButtonClick: false 
    };
  }

  handleNavClick = () => {
     this.setState({navButtonClick: true});
  }

  render(){
    const {navButtonClick} = this.state;

    return(
      <div className="XDashBoard">
        <DashTopNav onClick={this.handleNavClick}  />
        <FltBox navButtonClick />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

By using refs we can  access DOM nodes or React elements created in the render method in this example we will use refs to access the element that holds the `methodToFired` in `FltBox` component we will use `div` element thus we can access `methodToFired`.

then we will use that ref to the div element and pass it to whichever component we want in our case `DashTopNav` as a prop which is `onClick={this.parentClickHandler}`

```js
class FltBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  methodToFired(){
    alert('Fired from FltBox')
  }
  
  // here we use ref to access to the div element
  render() {
   return (<div ref={div => this.div = div}></div>);
  }
}

class DashTopNav extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  
  render(){
    return (
    <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>Submit</button>
    );
  }
 }
 
 class XDashBoard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.parentClickHandler = this.parentClickHandler.bind(this)
  }
  parentClickHandler() {
    this.mydiv.methodToFired();
  }
  render(){
    return(<div className="XDashBoard">
        <DashTopNav onClick={this.parentClickHandler}  />
        <FltBox ref={div => this.mydiv = div}/>
    </div>);
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<XDashBoard />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```